# Move focus to next control on enter key pressed with Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I need to let the users change to "next" textbox, combobox or button in a form when the press the Enter key (they CAN'T press Tab...)

I've found a couple of solutions (set a new event for each textbox's key pressed and set focus to the next control...) but I want this to have an easy manteinance.

Is there any magic around??

I've had problems even with tab navigation in silverlight...

Comment: Add xaml and some code samples how it is made now. And clarify what are you expecting to get.

Comment: Now it's working by pressing Tab button. I want to duplicate this to be done by enter button too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private void textBox3_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            if (Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift)
                textBox4.Focus();
            else
                textBox5.Focus();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That was just the solution I wanted to avoid... but I can't find any other 8-)